# CAS SSO for both web and stand alone applications

Tags: cas

I know CAS and I understand how it works in web applications contexts; now my customer would like to have a SSO system able in managing several applications (both stand alone and web applications)

I saw the RESTful APIs provided by CAS; I'ld like to use these APIs in my scenario but I'm missing how to use them.
Now...let's suppose I have the following applications:

- java swing application
- visual basic application
- web application (Java based)

What I would like to do is to use the CAS APIs in order to do a SSO so that an user logged on one of the previous applications must no more log in on the other. Is this possible? If so...how may I do it?
I guess that the first thing to do is to do the request for a CAS ticket but then....how can I share this ticket between applications? Is there any good way and/or best practice to follow?

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 1):

I already replied on the CAS mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jasig-cas-user/yhTwvj6-Sko...